# Ordenação (sort) de dados de uma List<Map>

Tags: java, spring

Preciso ordenar os valores de uma lista, a mesma está implementada da seguinte forma:

```
List<Map> mapas = new ArrayList();
```

A parte do código que faz a inserção dos dados:

```
for (DadoPicador obj : repository.findAllByPicadorDate(id, dataIni, dataFin)) {
        
            Map<String, String> mapTeste = Map.ofEntries(
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("date", obj.getDatahoraConsulta().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("consumo_combustivel_ao_dia", "" + obj.getConsumoCombustivelAoDia()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("consumo_combustivel_ao_mes", "" + obj.getConsumoCombustivelAoMes()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("horimetro_maquina", "" + obj.getHorimetroMaquina()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("horimetro_motor_na_lenta_diario", "" + obj.getHorimetroMotorNaLentaDiario()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("horimetro_motor_na_lenta_mensal", "" + obj.getHorimetroMotorNaLentaMensal()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("horimetro_producao_diario", "" + obj.getHorimetroProducaoDiario()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("horimetro_producao_mensal", "" + obj.getHorimetroProducaoMensal()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("nivel_radiador", "" + obj.getNivelRadiador()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("nivel_tanque_diesel", "" + obj.getNivelTanqueDiesel()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("pressao_oleo", "" + obj.getPressaoOleo()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("rpm", "" + obj.getRpm()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("temperatura_motor", "" + obj.getTemperaturaMotor()),
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("tensao_bateria", "" + obj.getTensaoBateria())
                     
            );
            
 
 
 


System.out.println(obj.getDatahoraConsulta().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString());
                mapas.add(mapTeste);
                cont++;
        
    }
```

Os dados do repository teoricamente estão vindo ordenados através de uma Query personalizada:

```
@Repository
public interface DadoPicadorRepository extends JpaRepository<DadoPicador, Long>{
   
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM dado_picador WHERE datahora_consulta >= :dataInicial and datahora_consulta <= :dataFinal and picador_id = :id ORDER BY datahora_consulta ASC", nativeQuery = true)
   List<DadoPicador> findAllByPicadorDate(@Param("id") long id, @Param("dataInicial") Instant dataInicial,  @Param("dataFinal") Instant dataFinal);

}
```

Porém ao rodar o System.out.println dentro do For, os dados não estão ordenados, conforme imagem abaixo, gerando problema em gráficos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resumindo, necessito ordenar a lista "mapas" com base na data-hora, que é do tipo Instant.**

Answer (score -3):

Isso está acontencendo porque a classe `HashMap` não tem ordenação dos itens inseridos, para manter ordenado de acordo com a ordem de inserção dos itens no mapa, você deve usar `LinkedHashMap`.

Você pode encontrar mais diferenças entre `HashMap` e `LinkedHashMap` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Como o nosso colega falou, um HashMap não garante a ordem dos seus elementos, o ideal seria então utilizar um LinkedMap. Esse sim, poderá garantir a ordem dos elementos de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Já para garantir que essa ordenação seja de fato feita, você pode simplesmente adicionar um "OrderByDatahoraConsulta" na sua query, ficando algo como

`List<DadoPicador> findAllByPicadorDateOrderByDatahoraConsulta(@Param("id") long id, Param("dataInicial") Instant dataInicial,  @Param("dataFinal") Instant dataFinal);`

> Essa query não precisa do @Query acima para funcionar